# Dynamically creating a spinner and setting its Value from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, spinner

**Found my problem check under "Update" for the code**

Okay, I have a problem loading the right value from Sqlite into my Spinner. Here is how my app is constructed

my onCreate() sets up a spinner called spinTypes by:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
 // local members . . . 
     .
     .
     .
 //spinner 
 private Spinner spinTypes, spinNames = null;

 // string array decl.
 private String [] types, names1, names2, names3 = null;

 // array adapters for string arrays
 private ArrayAdapter<String> typesAdapter, names1Adapter,
                             names2Adapter, names3Adapter;

 // create a Dbhelper object to access the db
 private DbHelper mdbHelper = null;

// on create
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedIstanceState){
  // call to super class
  // set my content view
  // instantiate all members 

  // Dbhelper object to access the db
  mdbHelper = new DbHelper(getBaseContext());

  // spinners
  spinTypes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_types);
  spinNames = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_names);

 // get string arrays from resources and create a ArrayAdapter<string>
 types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types);

 typesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);
 typesAdapter. setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 // want to create a dynamic spinner based on these arrays
 names1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_1); 
 names2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_2);
 names3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_3);

 // do this for all names++ arrays
 names1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names1);
 names1Adapter. setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 // etc . . . for the other two

 // set the adapter for the types spinner
 spinTypes.setAdapter(typesAdapter);

}
```

I have a creation method for inserting all my data into the db that works fine, my problem is when i want to try and populate the spinners for editing an entry.

The app works as so: you press an add button to popup a dialog that creates a list item in the calling view. I use two spinners to create it, one for the type which dynamically populates the second names spinner based on the type.

when i access the database object i return the strings from the spinner but for some reason when i create my if statement checking the position of the string in the array the second spinner sets position 0 every time.

the method including the if statement i mentioned above is as so:

```
public void populate(){
  mdbHelper.open();
  // if there is an item create a cursor rowId != null
  Cursor mTypes = mdbHelper.fetchItem(rowId);
   if(mTypes.moveToFirst()){
   String tType = mTypes.getString(mTypes.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_TYPE));
   String tName = mTypes.getString(mTypes.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_NAME));

  int t = spinTypes.getPosition(tType);
  spinTypes.setSelection(t);

  // ** this does not seem to do the job i want it to**
  if(t == 0){
    spinNames.setAdapter(names1Adapter); // set the adapter based on t value
    int n1 = names1Adapter.getPosition(tName); // use name return from db to get pos
    spinNames.setSelection(n1);            // set the position
  }else if(t ==1){
    spinNames.setAdapter(names2Adapter);
    int n2 = names1Adapter.getPosition(tName);
    spinNames.setSelection(n2);
  }else{
    spinNames.setAdapter(names3Adapter);
    int n3 = names3Adapter.getPosition(tName);
    spinNames.setSelection(n3);
  }

}// end populate

} // end class
```

The spinners all work but they do not end up on the value with tName i am returning.

Can anyone help with this?

** I am logging the name returned from the db and using it to find the index of the item in my error and i return the correct value, yet the spinner still defaults to 0**

Anyone know what my error may be? please

**Update(final code posted below)**
I made quite a bit of changes to get this to work, in order to understand what i did you should read this whole post so you don't miss anything!

added a variable before `onCreate()`
`private int spinNamePos;`

added this line after my last line of the `onCreate()`

```
// add a listener to the spinner
spinTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(TypesListener);
```

and created this listener as so

```
OnItemSelectedListener TypesListener = new OnItemSelectedListener(){
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
    // use the position of this spinner to set the second spinner
     switch(pos){
     case 0 :
        spinNames.setAdapter(names1Adapter);
        break;
      //etc. .  for the other two
     case 1:
        // etc
       break;
     }
     case 2:
        // etc
       break;
     }
     // created an int for the position of the second spinner before calling onCreate()
     // and use it to set this spinners position
     spinNames.setSelection(spinNamePos); 
 // this value is grabbed in onSavedInstanceState() and used to set the pos when onRestoreInstanceState() is called to handle orientation changes and activity paused
  }
 };
```

i then changed my `onPopulate()` to work as so calling a new method to set the second spinner's position

```
 public void populate(){
  mdbHelper.open();
  // if there is an item create a cursor rowId != null
  Cursor mTypes = mdbHelper.fetchItem(rowId);
   if(mTypes.moveToFirst()){
   String tType = mTypes.getString(mTypes.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_TYPE));
   String tName = mTypes.getString(mTypes.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_NAME));

  int t = spinTypes.getPosition(tType);
  spinTypes.setSelection(t);

  // call to the new method
  spinNamePos = setSpinNamesPos( t, tName);
  // set the position
  spinNames.setSelection(spinNamePos)


}// end populate

// new method to set the position when i want to update/change the list item

private int setSpinNamesPos(int m, String name){
 int pos = 0;
 switch(m){
  case 0:
    pos = names1Adapter.getPosition(name);
    break;
  case 1:
    pos = names2Adapter.getPosition(name);
    break;
   case 2:
    pos = names3Adapter.getPosition(name);
    break;
  }
 return pos;
}
```

**So happy to see this working any questions or comments are encouraged**

Comment: Do you have a mapping between the array of strings for the types `Spinner` to the other names arrays in your database? What exactly do you mean by the Spinner defaults to 0(you get(and set) the first adapter only or the selected item in the names spinner is set to 0 no matter what do you select)?

Comment: In the database i have two strings. I pull both with a cursor item then i use the first string to set the position of the first spinner which uses a string array resource. Then depending on this string i set either one of three adapters to my next spinner and then use the second string to find the position of this element in my array and try to set my spinner to that position of the adapter. But the second spinner keeps defaulting to the 0 index of the array.

Comment: This is strictly for updating an existing item in the db. My spinner works fine if I am adding an item. It is when i go to update the item that my second spinner is defaulting to the 0 index of the array everytime, but I am being returned the correct string from the db. for some reason when i call the `spinNames.setSelection(n1);` it does not set the position.

Comment: The `n1` value is different than `0`? Also, if you used this code to set the selection : `spin.post(new Runnable() {@Override
   public void run() {spin.setSelection(n1)}});` does the selection work?

Comment: No this just further complicates the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: The n1 could be 0 , 1 , 2, 3 because my array is length 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have seemed to figure out my own answer, weeks later! The problem I was having is that i was unaware that my `OnItemSelectedListener()` gets called every time my `adapter` is set for my first `spinner`.

So now realizing this, i set the first `spinner` in `OnItemSelectedListener()` then use this `spinner id` to set my second `spinner` `adapter`.(i.e based on the `id` I set the `adapter` of my second `spinner` to 1 of 3 choices.)

After this `adapter` is set I use the `value` returned from my `cursor` to find the string in this `adapter` and set the `spinner` to the `position` of the `string` in my `array`.

It all works great now and I will be putting the final code above under the **UPDATE** title. Thanks for all help.