# Use a spinner to set adapter of another spinner and a string to setSelection

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically creating a spinner and setting its Value from SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962268/dynamically-creating-a-spinner-and-setting-its-value-from-sqlite)

I was looking through other posts and find items similar to my issue but none as specific so here is it in short

The issue is that i am returning two strings from a database:

```
 tName, tType using a cursor object (see other post)
```

i then use the first `tType` to set the position of the first spinner, 
I have no problem with this because i am only using one adapter for this spinner.

Based on this string item i want to select from three other adapters using a switch 
statement. And set this adapter to my spinner then set the selection based on the string `tName`

Please help!
Full question and code at my other post:

[Dynamically creating a spinner and setting its Value from SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962268/dynamically-creating-a-spinner-and-setting-its-value-from-sqlite)

Comment: Don't create duplicates; if your original question needs a short summary, do that in there.

Comment: Sorry just trying to get an answer on this. I asked it late yesterday and no responses.